# Biblatex not working with Winedt

Tags: biblatex, winedt

I'm trying to merge the three chapters of my PhD thesis using `\subfile`, and I want the `.bib` files to be added at the end of each chapter. I'm trying with only one `.bib` file first and it doesn't work, ie. the output doesn't take into account my input `style=numeric` and doesn't print any bibliography (it just prints \biblio_chap1 at the end of the document !).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{/biblio_chap1.bib}

\title{PhD thesis}
\author{Anaïs}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}\subfile{Acknowledgements}

\chapter*{Introduction}\subfile{Intro}

\chapter{Paper 1}\subfile{chapter_1}
\printbibliography{/biblio_chap1}

\end{document}
```

And here is a minimal code for the chapter_1:

```
\documentclass{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
(CCRIF, 2017)\cite{ccrif} GDP\footnotemark{GDP 2016}
\end{document}
```

and for the .bib file

```
@techreport{ccrif,
 title = {CCRIF SPC Annual Report 2016-2017},
 author = {},
 group = {Caribbean Catastrophe Risk Insurance Facility},
 year = {2017},
 institution = {CCRIF SPC},
 address = {},
 month = {}
}
```

I have changed the execution mode accordingly from `bibtex.exe` to `biber.exe` and I compile using PDFTeXify. The bibliography works fine in a separate article, with the `\bibliography` command.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try compiling by hand (pdflatex >biber >pdflatex (twice)).

Comment: The thing is that with Winedt I think I have no option to run biber alone?

Comment: You can have, from the Configuration Components section of [WinEdt.org](http://www.winedt.org/config.html), download the WinEdt macro `LaTeXify` which adds some menu items and icons for the toolbar, among which a Biber menu/icon.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using a cluster where I have no administrator rights... And I can't find the `LaTeXify` macro?

Comment: There are no executable. It just installs WinEdt adhoc macros. Did you try? Other than that, can you play with the `Execution Modes` (Options menu)?

Comment: I have installed the `LaTeXify` macro. I have also played with the options of `Execution Modes` to swith from bibtex.exe to biber.exe. Now when I run Bibtex (after Pdflatex once) I get an error message `Cannot find '/biblio_chap1.bib'!`

Comment: Okay so now it works and I have the good bibliography, but some functions don't work anymore (especially the `\footnotemark`)

Comment: Could you post a minimal compilable code, reproducing the problem? Unrelated:  you shouldn't have to modify the `Execution Mode` with LaTeXify` since it adds a `Biber` item in the `TeX` menu (shortcut: Ctrl+Alt+B) and a `Biber` icon in the toolbar.

Comment: `\footnotemark` is unrelated to biblate+biber (normally). Again: please post a minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately the installation of `LaTeXify` has not added any icon in the toolbar... I have executed the macro script properly. I add a minimal code in my question

Comment: Now it works! With PDFTeXify. Thank you very much!